# Fiddler Web Debugger - Is it possible to filter by protocol (i.e. HTTP / HTTPS)?

Tags: fiddler

There appears to be no protocol filter in Fiddler Web Debugger (v 4.4.9.2).

I'm testing an HTTPS only implementation and it would be great if I could filter, or at least highlight non HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 0):

There are myriad ways to do this. For now, I'd suggest clicking the `Filters` tab and in the `Show only if URL contains` box, put `https://`